# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String] - Spring config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

we're using spring config server for environment specific properties and it was working fine.
All of a sudden without any change (or not able to identify what changed), spring boot application unable to start.

After enabling trace logs, spring config server values is resolved as LinkedHashMap instead of String.

For example, if the property is,

**influx.db.username = username**

This username value supposed to resolved as String. But in the trace logs,

```
     **Found key 'influx.db.username' in PropertySource 'bootstrapProperties' with value of type LinkedHashMap**
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'bootstrapProperties'
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams'
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams'
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'systemProperties'
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'systemEnvironment'
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'random'
2019-Dec-04 08:34:38 AM [main] [] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'influx.db.port' in PropertySource 'applicationConfigurationProperties'
```

From the logs, it is clear that the value type resolved as type of Map.

Where I can change the return type of this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by bumping to older version of our spring-cloud-config-server docker image.

registry.hub.docker.com/hyness/spring-cloud-config-server:2.1.4.RELEASE

We were using docker image from https://github.com/hyness/spring-cloud-config-server. Apparently, the recent changes in the Spring version upgrade break this issue.

And looks like this issue related to existing open issue with spring config server. 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1515

Comment: Facing the same issue while trying to use the config client in my microservices.